# Show that map is quotient map

Tags: general-topology

> Let $p:D^3\to \mathrm{SO}(3)$, where $p(x)$ is the identity matrix if $x=0$, otherwise $p(x)$ is the rotation by the angle $\pi ||x||$ around the line connecting the origin and $x$. Assume without proof that p is continuous. Show that $p$ is a quotient map.

I think I could show that by either using the universal property of the quotient topology or by the definition itself, i.e. $U\subseteq\mathrm{SO}(3)$ open iff $U$ open. I think the definition is easier since $p$ is continuous, thus one direction of the proof is already done. What is left to show is that $p$ is open, but I can't see a way to do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to assume that $p$ is continuous, you are already done by standard results: $D^3$ is compact, $SO(3)$ is Hausdorff so $p$ is then a closed map (as $A \subset D^3$ closed implies $A$ compact, so $p[A]$ compact as well by continuity, and so closed by Hausdorffness).

And a closed onto map is a quotient map (suppose $C \subset SO(3)$ is such that $p^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $D^3$, then $C = p[p^{-1}[C]]$ is closed in $SO(3)$, as required).